# Trouble with template declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am declaring a template in Visual Studio & I'm getting the error

IntelliSense: expected a ';'

What's wrong with my declaration?

```
template< typename PRIO, typename VALUE, typename CMP = std::less<PRIO> >
class Heap {};
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it.

Comment: Expect bugs for usage of perfectly valid c++ features when working with [tag:visual-studio-2010] :/ ...

Comment: @user3349665 _So what should I do?_ Use a newer VS version.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it different if you replace typename with class?

Comment: @Neil doesn't make any difference

Comment: Does your code build or is this just an error with VS IDE?

Comment: @txtechhelp My code is compiling. I guess it's a problem with VS2010's error detection.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up your IntelliSense database files? Close the project then delete the `.ncb` files associated with your project, reopen the project and IntelliSense rebuilds its database....?

Comment: IntelliSense is not a compiler. Do you get compilation errors? If so, provide more context (a couple of lines before and after the reported one).